# Compatility of older driver versions against newer mongodb server

Tags: mongodb

We have multiple applications using mongodb as database. In our current case our applications are using the mongo driver 3.4.

On the server side currently we are running with Mongo 3.4 but we would like to keep the Mongo version up to date as long as possible.

I know that mongo drivers provide such level of backward compatibility, but I don't know whether an old version of mongo driver can work without any problem with a newer version of a mongo server.

Can mongo driver 3.4 work with 3.6 server without any problem?

Comment: Without "Any" problem? Too broad a net. "Most" things should be okay, however there are some catches. The "catches" are listed in the release notes. Really most of it is more about "your code" than the driver itself. So without a thorough audit of your code, I don't think we're going to give you the rubber stamp you are looking for. Port to the new driver and if your code breaks in places, then those parts are actually what is incompatible, and not the driver itself.

Comment: It's clear that I cannot use any new features with the old driver. But it should be possible to say "mongodb server 3.6 is backward compatible for old mongo drivers for version X to Y".

Comment: To be clear. I'm voting to close as too broad because there are too many possible things to list. One big one I will note is the `aggregate()` method returns a default cursor from MongoDB 3.6. The "default" on driver code prior to this was the "single BSON document" response unless a cursor was asked for. Code that does not ask **explicitly** for a cursor or "explicitly does not ask" for the single document response will fail. This currently breaks `mongoose` releases prior to v5 as one example. Far too many edge cases to list here for a "rubber stamp". You need to work this one out yourself.

Comment: But I think this is a valid answer for my valid question. If you can enumerate just a single incompatibility problem, it means 3.6 is not fully backwards compatible with older driver versions. And this is what I want to learn. Thanks :)

Comment: Umm I didn't say that, and that's exactly my point. I for instance have code written on older drivers that works without fault on MongoDB 3.6 instances. But I also know for a fact that I have audited that code and I am fully aware that nothing it is doing breaks the rules of what the server expects. i.e I actually always called the aggregate cursors of the previous example, among other things. There is no Hard Yes or No here and it's solely up to your implemented code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Officially supported drivers provide a form of backward compatibility.

That is, newer drivers should be compatible with older server versions, but thorough testing of the application to double-check is always strongly recommended.

Note that the opposite is not always true, e.g. newer servers **may** be compatible with older drivers, but there is no guarantee. This is especially true if you apply [`setFeatureCompatibilityVersion` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/) after a server upgrade.

The page [Driver Compatibility](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/) in the documentation should be up-to-date with driver versions vs. server versions. You might be able to refer to this page in the future.

---

As of December 2021, the driver compatibility pages containing compatibility matrices for Python can be found at:

- PyMongo: https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/pymongo/#mongodb-compatibility
- Motor: https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/motor/#mongodb-compatibility